# parse does not return attributes in Rstudio test environment and Travis

Tags: r, unit-testing, parsing, testthat

The package `parseMe` has a single function

```
parseMe <- function(text) {
    parsed = parse(text = text)
    str(parsed) #for diagnosis
    getParseData(parse(text = parsed))
}
```

this function is tested using testthat

```
test_that('parseMe',{
    expect_that(parseMe('print("hey")'), is_a('data.frame'))
})
```

If one runs devtools::test() interactively from the Rstudio command line, this test passes. In the Rstudio testing environment however (v0.99.892) (when testing from the "build" tab) this test fails because `parse` function fails to return the attributes (visible on test output due to str). The same test also fails on travis-ci. What is the reason for this? How can it be solved?

Below are the links to the minimal test package that I use and travis testing log

- https://github.com/oganm/parseMe
- https://travis-ci.org/oganm/parseMe#L877

Comment: That indeed seems to be the issue. Why not answer?

Comment: Just did that myself. I'll accept it if you write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes are only retained if `parse(..., keep.source = TRUE)`. The default value for keep.source comes from `getOption("keep.source")` as per the `?parse` documentation. It's likely that the default option value is different run running R interactively vs non-interactively. If you want to always keep the source, you should make sure to set that to TRUE.